# Why the field has been cut into two parts in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Here is the code:

```
    -- create table novaya.unnormal as 
select query from  default.daily_session_mobile
where  dt = '20161020'
and page in ('/click_search_deal', '/click_search_product')
and query like '%memberID=33930938%'
and query like '%스텐드지퍼팩%'
```

The result only has one record and it is right
The value in the field of "query" is

> searchCount=52&rank=39&logType=click&currentView=/search_list&searchId=4c3ecee1354943e999e0c1566243bf87&logCategory=event&itemID=22780015&itemProductID=4&q=스텐드지퍼팩&memberID=33930938&productID=4993730&eventReferrer=/click_search_list&request_time=1476889555129&tz=+0900&appVersion=4.3.8&wl_mo=LG-F400L&wl_ma=LGE&wl_sn=Android&wl_v=4.4.2&wl_r=1440x2392&wl_l=ko&wl_c=KR

and there is no space in the value. We focus on the "q=스텐드지퍼팩&" in it.
It seems good.
But when I use `create table novaya.unnormal as select ...`
the table novaya.unnormal's query have been cut.
The new "query" only has a part of the whole query which is

> "searchCount=52&rank=39&logType=click&currentView=/search_list&searchId=4c3ecee1354943e999e0c1566243bf87&logCategory=event&itemID=22780015&itemProductID=4&q="
>   half of it is missing.
>   What is wrong with this?

Comment: Try setting "WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.encoding'='utf-8');" for your create statement

Comment: what is the 2nd query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a table using `create table novaya.unnormal as` statement, without specifying any input/output format and delimiters, all defaults will be chosen which probably causes the 스 character to act as a separator.

I suggest looking at the properties of the source table (`describe formatted default.daily_session_mobile`), and creating the new table with similar input/output format and delimiters. (setting them between `novaya.unnormal` and  `as`)